# Convert magento admin quote into a multi address order

Tags: magento

Say I have a quote from the admin create order with all the products already entered, how could I go about writing some code to add multiple shipping addresses and assign the item to the address.

Ive got some code working, based loosely off the frontend multiship model. The problem I'm having  is adding the multiple address and assigning the items to the quote. If I have a standard quote, how can I add the multiple addresses?

I've already tried :

```
 $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressID);
 $quote->addShippingAddress($address);
```

Which seems to only hold one address

The whole function:

```
 public function createMultiOrders() {
    // print_r($_POST);
    $items = $_POST['item'];
    $itemsByAddress = array();
    $billingInfo = array();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
        $quote = $session->getQuote();

        //first we are reorganizing the data provided by javascript into an array based on address ID's
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $addID = $item['addressID'];
            $itemID = $key;
            $qty = $item['qty'];
            $itemsByAddress[$addID][] = array('itemID' => $itemID, 'qty' => $qty);
        }
        // print_r($itemsByAddress);
        //now that we have an array of items, seperated by which addressid they goto, we can create the order for each address

        foreach ($itemsByAddress as $addressID => $items) {
            $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressID); 
            $quote->addShippingAddress($address);
            echo"<br/>address id is $addressID, items are: <br/>"; 
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // $address->addItem($_item);
                ///add items to order
                //  echo"id before is $item<br/>";
                $itemID = explode('-_', $item['itemID']);
                $itemID = $itemID[0];
                $qty = $item['qty'];
                echo "itemid is $itemID, qty is " . $qty . " <br/><br/><br/><br/>";
            }
        }
        //print_r(get_class_methods($quote));
        $shippingAddresses = $quote->getAllShippingAddresses();
        try {
            foreach ($shippingAddresses as $address) { 
                $order = $this->_prepareOrder($address);

                $orders[] = $order;
                Mage::dispatchEvent(
                        'checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single', array('order' => $order, 'address' => $address)
                );
            }

            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $order->place();
                $order->save();
                if ($order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                }
                $orderIds[$order->getId()] = $order->getIncrementId();
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setOrderIds($orderIds);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setLastQuoteId($quote->getId());

            $quote->setIsActive(false)->save();

            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_submit_all_after', array('orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $quote));

            return $this;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_multishipping_refund_all', array('orders' => $orders));
            throw $e;
        }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, were you essentially trying to copy over the frontend multi-shipping order feature for the admin?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was actually able to finish this in other ways. We are releasing it as an extension. The extension adds multi address order capability to magento admin, where it is currently non existent.

Comment: @MSD were you able to create this extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue and successfully was able to write a  script to turn an ordinary admin order into a multi address order. One of the mistakes that messed with me the entire time was the way I loaded the admin quote:

I was loading the session like this

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
```

and it should be

```
$session = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/session_quote');
```

Now, as far as assigning each of the quote items to an address, the final code looks like:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressID);
echo"<br/>address id is $addressID<br/>";

echo"quote address not set, adding shipping address <br/>";
$quoteAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($address);
$quote->addShippingAddress($quoteAddress);
$quoteAddressItem = $quoteAddress->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getId());
if ($quoteAddressItem) {
  echo"increasing item quantitiy for quote address<br/>";
  // $quoteAddressItem->setQty((int) ($quoteAddressItem->getQty() + $qty));
} else {
echo"setting customer id for quote item<br/>";
$quoteItem->setCustomerAddressId($quoteAddress->getCustomerAddressId());
echo"adding item to quote address<br/>";
$quoteAddress->addItem($quoteItem)->setQuote($quote);
echo"adding item to quote collection<br/>";


if (!$quoteAddress->getItemsCollection()->getItemById($quoteItem->getId())) {
    $quoteAddress->getItemsCollection()->addItem($quoteItem)->save();
}
$quoteAddress->setCollectShippingRates(TRUE);
$quoteAddress->collectShippingRates();
$quoteAddress->save();
$quoteItem->save();
$quote->save();
```

}

Comment: does it take care of shopping cart rules as well? Can we have same address and still split order into 2 parts as per in my case some products can be shipped with specific shipping method so I need to have two orders each with separate shipping method but same shipping address.